# Как сравнить два аудиофайла?

Tags: алгоритм, аудио, распознавание

Требуется, например, звук глотания отличить от кашля.

Думаю, что можно создать "идеальные" аудиофайлы, но как сравнить их с вновь записанными? Все что вижу в инете связано с распознаванием речи и уже под это заточено.

Есть ли что-то для сравнения двух аудиофайлов и определения их похожести?

Comment: Могу писать на c++ и vb.net, немного java, но впринципе буду рад увидеть реализацию хоть на чем-нибудь

Comment: Этим занимается целая отрасль науки, и это за неделю вряд ли можно реализовать - необходим подсчет темпа, ритма, АЧХ, тональности и не только.

Comment: @Etki совершенно согласен. Я изначально обратил внимание именно на то, что вопрос сугубо теоретический и породит дискуссию. Так оно и получилось. Так что желание автора увидеть "код хоть на чем-то" так и останется несбыточным ;)

Comment: Один слушать правым ухом, другой левым

Comment: классификация сигнала с шумом (кашель vs. глотание) хорошо для нейросетей подходит ([объяснение почему](https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-theory-cracks-open-the-black-box-of-deep-learning-20170921/)). Пример: [Urban Sound Classification](http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Хотя данный вопрос подразумевает ответ, который невозможно дать однозначно, но можно наметить примерный путь поисков. По крайней мере вы будете знать с чего начать и куда стоит двигаться для достижения цели.

Для самого начала стоит обратится к изучению аналогово-цифрового преобразования звука и узнать, как вообще звук представляется в дискретном состоянии и какие параметры в него входят. Так же можно изучить аналоговые и дискретные звуковые преобразования. Так вы сможете ознакомится с довольно интересной природой звука и что он из себя представляет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, вы должны составить для себя список, какие факторы можно использовать для определения различий между требуемым списком звуковых сигналов. Это может быть в простом случае один фактор, в сложных целая сеть различных характеристик сигнала и всевозможных алгоритмов обработки. Кстати много много названий характеристик в вики, можно их посмотреть и изучить спектральный анализ звука. В любом случае Вам понадобится собрать базу данных из таких слепков и сравнивать ее между собой для анализа и проектирования программы.

Далее вы пишите программу, которая сможет анализировать входящие сигналы и путем сравнения выдавать оценочный результат. Вам не нужно создавать идеальные файлы и сравнивать, Вам нужно создать допустимые плавающие границы для входных сигналов. Примерно так и работают искусственные сети, обучаясь на формировании оценочных признаков и их диапазонов в базе данных.

Примерно так Вы сможете создать очень примитивную, но зато свою, систему распознавания.

Answer (score 10):

Очевидно, если вы нашли примеры распознавания речи, то пример распознавания нейросетью изображения вам найти не составит труда.

Есть немножко туповатый, но вполне работающий способ распознавания звуков по их графическому "изображению" при котором требуется лишь базовое знание нейросетей на уровне 2-3 курса ВУЗа. Для этого нужно:

**Подготовка:**

1) Записать сэмплы эталонных команд, которые вы собираетесь распознавать.
(Количество распознаваемых команд зависит от каскадности используемой нейросети и способа её обучения)

2) Сформировать для каждого сэмпла графики зависимости амплитуды(громкости) от времени и сохранить их в виде Bitmap.

3) Нормализовать полученные изображение по размеру (все изображения должны быть одинаковы по размеру)

4) Обучить нейросеть на полученные эталонные изображения.

**Работа:**

1) Получить потоковый звук с микрофона

2) Определить границы распознаваемого фрагмента по околонулевым значениям амплитуды (тишина)

3) Сформировать для записанного сэмпла график зависимости амплитуды(громкости) и получить Bitmap

4) Масштабировать Bitmap до тех же размеров, что и эталонные

5) Распознать полученное изображение, подав на вход нейросети.

В данном случае распознавание звука сводится к классическому распознаванию изображений, примеров которого в интернете достаточно много. В качестве источника для изображения может использоваться не только амплитуда, но и любая другая зависимость, делающая фрагмент гарантированно уникальным.

Данный метод - это редкостный изврат, но он работает (проверял еще в 2003 году)и требует от программиста лишь базовых навыков по созданию нейросетей (а с появлением Vuforia и OpenCV и их не нужно) и околонулевых знаний в МатАне.

В чем то вам может помочь вот эта [статья на Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/220061/)

*P.S. Если же все же решитесь делать "по-человечески" - вот статья, с которой стоит начать: [Простыми словами о преобразовании Фурье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196374/)*

Answer (score 4):

> Как сравнить два аудиофайла?

1. Ответить самому себе на вопрос: *какие конкретно* алгоритмические **различия** должны быть выделены;
2. Потратить годы на изучение технологий распознавания и анализа речи/звуков;
3. Накопить целевую экспертизу;
4. Вовлечь в проект специалистов по теме;
5. Реализовать проект и получить PROFIT;
6. Стать с новой технологией вторым Марком Цукербергом.

Как-то так.

Я совсем не понимаю тех, кто проголосовал за поднятие этого вопроса. Наверное, это просто было бы круто, вот так вот взять и привести здесь код, который "различал" бы два аудио-файла по неизвестно каким требованиям и параметрам.

Наверняка именно это и побудило апвотеров так проголосовать. Но вопрос, на мой взгляд, глубоко теоретический, затрагивающий весьма специфические технологии, которые до сих пор "сидят" в инкубаторах крупных технологических компаний, и в которые [технологии] инвестируются миллионы долларов.

Короче говоря, этот вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа, потому что он, во-первых, задан без необходимых условий и дополнений; а во-вторых, задан без предварительного самостоятельного поиска решений.

Если уж очень хочется ответ на именно такой вопрос – используйте для сравнения HEX-редактор ;)

Comment: Например, я проголосовал за этот вопрос, потому что мне реально интересно, каково состояние развития технологий по этой теме на сегодняшний день, и что можно сделать программисту, не являющемуся частью большой компании (Фурье-анализ? разделение на тон и шум? психоакустическая модель? популярные эвристики?). То есть мне тоже интересен ответ, значит, вопрос неплох. Другое дело, если на текущее время ответ лишь «ничего не возможно». Но отрицательный ответ — тоже ответ.

Comment: @VladD, был уверен, что этот вопрос быстро прикроют и **рад, что ошибся** (*что-то меняется на ru.SO*). Что же касается существа дела, то не будучи специалистом, могу предположить, что тут на результаты спектрального анализа надо натравить нейронную сеть (и возможно закончить обработкой ее результатов (по разным временным интервалам) чем-то вроде diff).

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, общий настрой сообщества меняется. И это хорошо.

Comment: У тебя в ответе допущение, что сравнить = распознать. На самом деле, вполне возможно, что это не так. Я, например, делал очистку фотографий с текстом от фона, чтобы можно было печатать на белом фоне - замечательно работает, и мне при этом совсем не понадобилось распознавать текст. Так же и тут - вполне возможно, что сравнение делается достаточно просто. Но да, ответить на него без примеров достаточно затруднительно, если сам чего-то подобного не делал. А вообще, что касается распознавания речи - вроде современный уровень технологий это вполне позволяет.

Answer (score 4):

Спектральный анализ Вам в помощь. Предполагаю, что первым этапом будет собрать набор сэмплов, получить их спектры. Построить обобщенную модель "идеального" кашля. Дальше проводить корреляционный анализ используя те же сэмплы. Корректировать форму спектра/функцию его описывающую и по новой.

Comment: Ну, спектральный анализ — это как бы азбука. А что дальше?

Comment: Я не говорил, что будет просто. Предполагаю, что первым этапом будет собрать набор сэмплов, получить их спектры. Построить обобщенную модель "идеального" кашля. Дальше проводить корреляционный анализ используя те же сэмплы. Корректировать форму спектра/функцию его описывающую и по новой.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл дописать в ответ ту информацию?

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю обратить внимание на некоторые особенности в файле. Например, динамика увеличения и уменьшения громкости относительно среднего уровня, разброс и динамика частот и т. д. Скорее всего, при отсутствии необходимости распознавать речь, чего-то простого будет достаточно для решения поставленной задачи (по крайней мере, при небольшом числе образцов).

Answer (score 2):

В интернете есть попытки реализовать библиотеки выполняющие схожие функции.
Если я вас правильно понял, то вот библиотека для Java:
[musicg](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/).

В общем попробуйте использовать поиск Google. Если у вас есть небольшие проблемы с английским - к сожалению вам придется его подтянуть, чтобы иметь возможность искать и находить проекты не переведенные на русский язык и не озвученные русскоязычным сообществом. Вот вам ссылка на ответ в англоязычной версии [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761141/java-sdk-for-comparing-sounds).